# ArrayList capacity does not exceed 32768

Tags: c#, arraylist, collections

I have a method which returns large number of rows from a database. (Please see following)

```
public static ACollection GetListFromDatabase(string customername)
    {
        DBFactory factory = DBFactory.Instance;
        ACollection custcol = new ACollection();
       //This is a collection class extended from System.Collections.CollectionBase

       System.Data.IDataReader reader = null;

        try
        {
            reader = factory.GPDb.ExecuteReader("spGetCustomerInfo", customernumber);
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ACollection cust = ACollection.ListFromReader(reader); // returns info and assign it to ACollection object.
                custcol.InnerList.Add(cust);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            String error = e.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.Close();
        }
        return custcol;
    }
```

When I run this method, I realized that count of custcol.InnerList is 32767 where it supposed to be around 34000. Then I saw that it gets into exception.

The error message says that "Value was either too large or too small for an Int16."

I believe, the capacity of this arraylist gets assigned as int16 in somehow. Can somebody help me to increase the capacity ?

Thanks

**Edit:** 
here is the full stack trace

```
   at System.Convert.ToInt16(Int64 value)
   at System.Int64.System.IConvertible.ToInt16(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ToInt16(Object value)
   at Quest___Shared.CustomerCrossReference.ListFromReader(IDataReader reader) in C:\vsproject\CustomerCrossReference.cs:line 105
   at Quest___Shared.ACollection.GetListFromDatabase(String customernumber) in C:\vsproject\ACollection.cs:line 88
```

[image: Full exception screen]

Comment: A DataTable can hold 16,777,216 rows

Comment: Are you sure it's a problem with `ArrayList`?  Does your implementation of `ACollection.ListFromReader` attempt to assign a large 32- or 64-bit column value to a 16-bit property of whatever `cust` is?  Or perhaps it's assigning a negative column value to a `ushort` property?  Being able to see the entire stack trace of the exception might help determine this.

Comment: I doubt your analysis. But ArrayList is pretty much deprecated anyway. Use a List<T> instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the type of the variable that is giving you problems to `Int32` or `Int64`, then you will be able to insert bigger or smaller numbers.